# How to share a model with multiple Controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

I've got a first UISplitViewController in wich there is (and it's default) two other view Controller as children and for one of them there is another view controller as child (again it's default).

My problem is that the Model, which is basically a class, used by the business logic is created in the AppDelegate and i'd like to use it in every controller.

I tried to use the viewDidLoad method to pass the model through all the controller but this method is called in the last child and then go through the hierarchical tree to the SplitViewController.

Two constraints i'd like to fullfill are:

- I don't want to use a singleton
- I don't want all my controllers to know the AppDelegate

Is there a way to to this?

Comment: What is the reason for "I don't want to use a singleton"

Comment: I was asked to limit the dependecies at the lowest.

Comment: I agree with @GrzegorzKrukowski, singletons actually provide a simplistic way of initiating a class. you just call the method instead of having to do alloc/init every time

Comment: "I was asked to limit the dependecies at the lowest."  A singleton of the model class is the lowest.  The view controllers don't need to know about `AppDelegate` just the model object.

Comment: It's lower than every controllers knowing the AppDelegate but since it's like a global variable, every controllers would be linked to this unique variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use singleton for any reason you have you can just pass model through those ViewControllers. Just create custom initWithModel: method for each of ViewControllers you have when you create them and hierarchically pass data to them. Maybe create a base class for all of them to keep it common.

For storyboard you can assign model in prepareForSeque method, just after creating ViewControllers.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"myViewController"])
     {
         [segue.destinationViewController setModel:self.model];
     }
}
```

Comment: Since i used the storyboard, i'm not calling the init myself and i don't know which init method is called by the storyboard. But if i can override the initWithModel method knowing it will be the one called by the storyboard, it's perfect.

Comment: You can pass your model inside prepareForSeque method

Comment: @trojanfoe yes but with a singleton i loose control of who is using the model, with this method i keep control on which controller is using the model

Comment: @Cratein I'm not sure how important that is.  However passing it explicitly is always better than using a global.

Comment: @Grzegorz Krukowski will seque work even for non Navigation controller?

Comment: @Cratein what you mean ? Do you have child controller embeded in xib ?

Answer (score 0):

That could be an answer :

in the `.h` :

```
+(MyModel *)shared;
```

in the `.m` :

```
static MyModel *myModel;

@implementation MyModel

+(MyModel *) shared{
    if (nil != myModel) {
        return myModel;
    }

    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        myModel = [[MyModel alloc] init];
    });
    return myModel;
}
```

In this way, you can access to your model anywhere of your app.

Hope that will help!

EDIT: add of `dispatch_once`

Comment: `dispatch_once()` is the preferred method of creating the singleton.

Comment: That could be an answer but i would like to try another solution before coming to the singleton solution